# Codeigniter: Send whole POST request to method of another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, parameters

I have a general controller which will get the `POST` request and decide to call known method of any controller. The controller will be chosen according to request.

Also I need to send whole `POST` request to chosen method without tampering.

---

**More Description**
Getting post request in `controller 1`, handling the request and decide to call `known_method()` of `controller X | X != 1`. Also sending primary request to the method.  E.g.

```
public function index()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();

    //handling the request and decide to call the following method of another controller

    Controller_X->known_method($post);
    //OR
    redirect("site_url/controller_X/known_method/{$post}");
}
```

But because sending `$post` as parameter as it will send as `GET` request, may tamper it's data, it's not practical way. Also storing in `session` and retrieve that in target method is not a good solution.

---

**Question:** How I can send this data to my selected target?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can just include the controller inside a controller

```
if(toIncludeController_a()){
      $this->load->library('../controllers/Controller_a');
      $this->controller_a->myFunction(); //<- this function can also get the post data using $this->input->post
}
```

contoller_a:

```
public function myFunction(){
     $data = $this->input->post();
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Does not have any performance issue? causing low speed or these kind of problem?

Comment: your welcome, and no, there's no problem with that, it's more lite than loading the entire CI again when redirecting

Comment: Thanks again, I'll test the solution and will mark it as correct after success

Comment: I do this `$this->load->library('../controllers/xxx')` but I get this error: `Unable to locate the specified class: Simanaz.php`! Also directly I can access the controller as `site_url/simanaz`

Comment: what is exactly your class name and the php class name? including caps

Comment: `Simanaz` & `Simanaz.php`. instead of loading I just include it and its work.

Comment: I marked your answer, You can append `include` solution for future visitor. Thanks

Comment: @DanielKrom: Mate thanks it worked like a charm. one question how about getting uri segment ($this->uri->segment(x)), inside an other controller because when you will pass:  $this->controller_a->myFunction(x); from first conroller, I'm unable to get it on another controller via uri segment.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions, which I think would be cleaner:

1) Let the request handling in library, instead of controller. Call the library accordingly.

```
if(request1) {
    $this->load->library('lib1');
    $this->lib1->handle(); // in lib1, retrieve all post without tampering
} else if(request2) {
    ...and so on
}
```

2) Handle the decision request in the client or js

Redirection won't work as data would be lost or need to be reposted.

Update/comment: Library is not helper or meant to be lite, it is better viewed as business logic. Operations or heavy logic are commonly placed here, and model interaction as well.

Comment: That's an idea, but helpers are good for light operations. Now I need to do some complicated operations in my `X controllers`, so helpers are not the point. Also if I have to redirect, Data somehow must attach to redirection like session or etc. Yes as you said data will be lost without strategy